# SQL query is returning multiple rows for the same key - pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, sccm

I am attempting to create a report from my SCCM SQL database using SSRS.  The SQL query I am running in SSRS looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    SYS.Netbios_Name0, 
    SYS.User_Name0, 
    OPSYS.Caption0 as Caption, 
    OPSYS.Version0,
    CSYS.Model0,
    Netcard.Description0, 
    Netcard.MACAddress0, 
    Netcard.Manufacturer0,
    BIOS.SerialNumber0 as 'BiosSerial0',
    WD.SerialNumber0 as 'WDSerial0',
    ENC.SMBIOSAssetTag0,
    WD.LastUpdate0,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), wd.WarrantyStartDate0, 106) as WarrantyStartDate0,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), wd.WarrantyEndDate0, 106) as WarrantyEndDate0

FROM 
    fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs)  SYS
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY(@UserSIDs)  MEM on SYS.ResourceID = MEM.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM(@UserSIDs)  CSYS on SYS.ResourceID = CSYS.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_PROCESSOR(@UserSIDs)  Processor  on Processor.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM(@UserSIDs)  OPSYS on SYS.ResourceID=OPSYS.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_PC_BIOS(@UserSIDs) BIOS on SYS.ResourceID=BIOS.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE(@UserSIDs) ENC on SYS.ResourceID=ENC.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN  fn_rbac_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER(@UserSIDs) Netcard ON SYS.ResourceID = Netcard.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN fn_rbac_GS_WESLEYANDEVICE(@UserSIDs) WD on SYS.ResourceID=WD.ResourceID

WHERE     (Netcard.Description0 LIKE '%I219-V%') OR (Netcard.Description0 LIKE '%Wireless-AC 8265%') AND (Netcard.MACAddress0 IS NOT NULL)

ORDER BY WD.WarrantyEndDate0 ASC
```

This query returns the results I want but it creates a new row, including some duplicate information, for every result in the Netcard fields. For example, I have one computer with multiple network interfaces (limited by my WHERE statement above).  The two network adapters I am searching for are returned but on individual rows:

[image: current results]

I would like for there to be only one row per computer and the data returned by the Netcard fields would be in a new column in the same row.   I am unsure how to proceed as I am not well versed in SQL or DBA.  I am assuming this would be a pivot but I am not sure how to do that (specifically keying).  This is an example of what I am hoping to achieve:

[image: example of what I am hoping to achieve]

Thank you for helping me find the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you add DISTINCT in your select clause.

Comment: Do you know the max number of card that can be in the machines?

Comment: Use a PIVOT: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Shawn Thank you, I will check out using a PIVOT. 

There are only two adapters in each machine. However, I am looking through the results and there are at most 4 mac addresses (2 for wired, 2 for wireless) listed - likely from some sort of repair/swap. Most results have two. I did run into some duplicates...one machine has 10 mac addresses listed. I think that SCCM has some garbage in the database.

Comment: @Aurelian I can add DISTINCT to my select clause. When I ran the query I get an error saying that ORDER BY is expected in the select clause. I will play around and see if this leads to anything.

Comment: Holy function!!!! This looks like some things have gone awry in design. You have function after function here and each of them are receiving what appears to be a delimited string. You will have to provide some details if you want real help here. What are all these functions doing? And then you will need a dynamic pivot or dynamic crosstab.

Comment: @SeanLange SCCM is an _extremely_ convoluted system. The pieces of it I've worked with make me want to cry.

Comment: @Shawn are you saying that all the function craziness is because that is how MS built it? Ugh!!! Wouldn't be the first time they built something so horrific it is nearly unusable. Probably won't be the last either. I stand by my statement that something went wrong in the design. ;)

Comment: Would putting those multiple Netcard values into 1 XML data type or JSON or concatinated string in an NVARCHAR perhaps be an option for you? If there's really 1 with 10 cards, a pivot would add a lot of columns.

Comment: @SeanLange yes, something went wrong in design. I've just been tacking onto this report that I inherited with the SCCM instance. I am going to try the suggestion in the answer below and see what happens. If that doesn't work, I'll pivot.

Answer (score 0):

using this dataset result also, you can manage the pivot in ssrs report i.e. you can create a pivot in ssrs report tool.

create new .RDL file and create new dataset to access the data on report to display.

like table you use "Matrix" control on RDL and bind the dataset to the Matrix control and in column group add your column name that you want to display as pivot
and check the report

Comment: I think this answer is assuming that I have Visual Studio available to use with the SSDT integration. Luckily, I have it and will give the matrix control a shot.